# How to get the mean of pandas cut categorical column

Tags: python, pandas

I was using pandas cut for the binning continuous values. I wonder how to get the mean for each bin.

## MWE

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(1,10,10)})
df['bins_a'] = pd.cut(df['a'],4)

print(df)
   a        bins_a
0  9    (7.0, 9.0]
1  9    (7.0, 9.0]
2  4    (3.0, 5.0]
3  8    (7.0, 9.0]
4  8    (7.0, 9.0]
5  1  (0.992, 3.0]
6  5    (3.0, 5.0]
7  3  (0.992, 3.0]
8  6    (5.0, 7.0]
9  3  (0.992, 3.0]
```

I tried:

```
df['bins_a_mean'] = df['bins_a'].mean()

But this fails.
```

How to get the means for each interval?

Comment: `df.groupby('bins_a')['a'].mean()`

Comment: what your expected response?

Comment: I need bins_a mean for each row.

Comment: What does _this fails_ mean!?

Comment: @MilkyWay001 Of course, but there are many different ways things can fail. For example, someone could fail to explain the error they're facing, which causes someone else to fail to understand the issue ;p

Comment: @MilkyWay001 _No any other motives rather than simply learn how to coding and use pandas._ Don't worry, you're in the right place :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df['bins_a_mean'] = df.groupby('bins_a')['a'].transform('mean')

print(df)
   a        bins_a  bins_a_mean
0  9    (7.0, 9.0]     8.500000
1  9    (7.0, 9.0]     8.500000
2  4    (3.0, 5.0]     4.500000
3  8    (7.0, 9.0]     8.500000
4  8    (7.0, 9.0]     8.500000
5  1  (0.992, 3.0]     2.333333
6  5    (3.0, 5.0]     4.500000
7  3  (0.992, 3.0]     2.333333
8  6    (5.0, 7.0]     6.000000
9  3  (0.992, 3.0]     2.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to use the mid attribute of the pd.Interval class.

```
df.bins_a.apply(lambda x: x.mid)

0    8.000
1    8.000
2    4.000
3    8.000
4    8.000
5    1.996
6    4.000
7    1.996
8    6.000
9    1.996
```

This method returns the midpoint of the interval and is not dependent on the distribution of 'a' inside the bin unlike @BhishanPoudel answer.